# How to generate <a> tag from input fields

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.Net (in C#), I need to generate a  tag that contains person's name, address, etc.  I have barely any experience with ASP.NET (or .NET languages) and I am given this assignment.  Could someone please guide me to correct path please?

Link should look like this:

https://example.com/PRR/Info/Login.aspx?SupplierId=36&RegisteredUserLogin=T000001&Mode=RegisteredLoginless&RegisteredModeFunction=AutoShowTotals&RegisteredModeFunction=AutoShowTotals&PayerCountry=FI&ForcePayerEmail=al@lea.al.banthien.net&ExternalOrderId=1000123&ServiceId=286&Amount286=5000.00&PayerInfo286=T000001|10000123|type1|m&SuccessReturnURL=http://success.html&FailureReturnURL=http://failure.html&SuccessCallbackURL=http://youpay.com/p247/success.html&FailureCallbackURL=http://yourfailure.html

following components/fields needs to be sent to API in order to pre-populate information for users:
FirstName,
LastName,
SupplierID = integer,
Person's userlogin (Should increment by 1. Example: person 1 = t00001. Person2 = t00002, etc.),
PayerCountry,
Email,
amount

For some reason, my management thinks that this is something a non-technical person can do!  Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: That is an interesting url.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I need to generate an HTML link"?  Do you mean, you need to take the input fields and generate an `<a>` tag for your page?

Comment: Silly thing, but if you are a non-technical person you might consider changing your username to "notaprogrammer"...

Comment: Perhaps you should tell management that they are supremely moronic for using a link like that. I love a good game of "set your own price for this product", but I'm sure they won't.

Comment: @McGarnagle,  Yes you are correct.  I need to take the input fields and generate an <a> tag for the clients page.

Comment: you should use a form with `Get` method. it'll be a lot easier and clean.

Answer (score 1):

I like to set up a data structure first for this kind of massive string construction.  In this case a dictionary works:

```
string CreateUrl(string firstName, string lastName, int supplierID, int login, string payerCountry, string email, decimal amount)
{
    int personId = 0;
    var query = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "SupplierId",              "36" },
        { "RegisteredUserLogin",     "T" + login.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0') },
        { "Mode",                    "RegisteredLoginLess" },
        { "RegisteredModeFunction",  "AutoShowTotals" },
        { "PayerCountry",            payerCountry },
        { "ForcePayerEmail",         email },

        // etc ...

        { "FailureCallbackURL", "http://yourfailure.html" },
    };

    string baseUrl = "https://example.com/PRR/Info/Login.aspx?";

    // construct the query string: 
    // join the key-value pairs with "=" and concatenate them with "&"
    // URL-encode the values
    string qstring = string.Join("&",
        query.Select(kvp => 
            string.Format("{0}={1}", kvp.Key, HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value.ToString()))
        )
    );

    return baseUrl + qstring
}
```

(Note that the query string values have to be URL-encoded to ensure that they do not conflict with reserved URL characters like "&".)

Now you can construct the URL in your ASPX page:

```
<script runat="server">
    public string URL
    {
        get
        {
            // TODO insert the user's fields here
            return CreateUrl(FirstName, LastName, ...);
        }
    }
</script>

<a href='<%= URL %>'>Login</a>
```

One other note -- it sounds like you want to construct an auto-incrementing ID for new users.  This is easiest to do by using a database (the database can handle concurrency and persistence more easily than a web server).  I suggest inserting a record into a table with an auto-increment field, and using the database-generated value as the ID.